# Query based on Fields existing in different Indices in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I've got the following query

```
{
   "from":0,
   "size":50000,
   "_source":[
      "T121",
      "timestamp"
   ],
   "sort":{
      "timestamp":{
         "order":"asc"
      }
   },
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":{
            "range":{
               "timestamp":{
                  "gte":"2017-01-17 11:44:41.347",
                  "lte":"2017-02-18 11:44:47.878"
               }
            }
         },
         "must":{
            "exists":{
               "field":"T121"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

http://172.22.23.169:9200/index1,index2,Index3/_search?pretty

With this URL i want to query over a number of indices in Elasticsearch and only return those documents where a specific field exists.

Is it possible to put in a list of fields in the "exists" clause where i define
if "field1" OR "field2" OR "fiedl3" are existing in one of the documents return it, otherwise don't, or do i have to script such a case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To search across all indices use > http://172.22.23.169:9200/_search?pretty

To search across selected indices add following filter to "bool" filter

```
"must": {
  "terms": {
    "_index": [
      "index1",
      "index2"
    ]
  }
}
```

For OR'ing multiple "exists", you can use should clause with multiple exists and specify "minimum_should_match" to control searched records.

```
{
  "from":0,
  "size":50000,
  "_source":[
    "T121",
    "timestamp"
  ],
  "sort":{
    "timestamp":{
      "order":"asc"
    }
  },
  "query":{
    "bool":{
      "must":{
        "range":{
          "timestamp":{
            "gte":"2017-01-17 11:44:41.347",
            "lte":"2017-02-18 11:44:47.878"
          }
        }
      },
      "should":[
        {
          "exists":{
            "field":"field1"
          }
        },
        {
          "exists":{
            "field":"field2"
          }
        },
        {
          "exists":{
            "field":"field3"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```